# Find files modified in last hour that contain certain word

Tags: find

I want to find files modified in the last hour which contain a certain number. I currently have the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -0.5 | grep -lir "100"
```

This is returning all files with with the number even if was not modified in last hour.

Thanks.

Comment: you're missing some `-`, e.g. `-maxdepth` and `-mtime`. Your command gives for me ERROR: `find: unknown predicate -0.5`. And if I fix it, I get `find: invalid argument -0.5' to -mtime'`. So not sure what you're doing... afaik, `-mtime` only accepts positive integer values.

Comment: Files that contain? Or files with names that contain? Using `grep -r` suggests the former, but the act of piping from `find` to `grep` suggests the latter.

Comment: Hi Kamil, I'm trying to find files that contain. Not within the file name :)

Comment: @pLumo What do you mean by "positive"? `-mtime -5`, `-mtime 5` and `-mtime +5` are all valid and no two are equivalent.

Comment: Hi pLumo, mistake on my part. i've added -maxdepth and -mtime to the question. Even if I try to search for day so  '-1' instead of '-0.5' it doesnt work as expected

Comment: man find: "File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.", so what you think should -5*24 mean??

Comment: @pLumo [This](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), where it says `Less than n.`

Comment: Similar: [Search for last modified files in the last 2 minutes in your home directory which contain a certain string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/578221/315749)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there has been a transcription error here between what you're actually doing and what you've sanitised to present here — because I wouldn't expect the command in the original post to either do what you're asking, nor to behave in the manner you have described.  I'd expect it to not work at all, to be honest.

Depending on the version of tools available, this should do what you're looking for.

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -mmin -61 -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "100"
```

You may need to adjust/remove the `-maxdepth 1` if you're wanting to do some traversal of subdirectories.

Comment: Hey Thanks! This is what I was after